# Including special character in Basemodel for Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to create a Pydantic basemodel with a key including a '$' sign. It looks like this:

```
class someModel(BaseModel):
    $something:Optional[str] = None
```

Then I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
But I need to keep the key name `$something` to use in other parts. Is there a way to allow the dollar sign in this case?

Comment: Can you explain why you need the `$` symbol on the attribute name? it is not a valid python name.

Comment: Thanks, that's because I need to pass it to a request body. I could convert to string and put the $ sign to communicate with other services but I was wondering how this issue should be handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Field(alias=...)` to use a different (valid) variable name.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    something: Optional[str] = Field(alias="$something", default=None)
```

I've also added a default value of `None` since you had that in your code.

Here's a working example (**EDIT: Updated to show how to get alias for your variable name if you need to use it later**):

```
import logging
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)-9s %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = FastAPI()


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    something: Optional[str] = Field(alias="$something", default=None)


@app.post("/")
async def root(request: Request, parsed_body: SomeModel):

    # A dict of all the model fields and their properties
    LOGGER.info(f"SomeModel.__fields__: {SomeModel.__fields__}")

    # To get the alias of the variable name
    something_alias = SomeModel.__fields__["something"].alias
    LOGGER.info(f"something_alias: {something_alias}")

    # Edit: prefer to use "parsed_body_by_alias" than raw_body. Leaving here to show the difference.
    raw_body: bytes = await request.body()
    LOGGER.info(f"raw_body: {raw_body}")

    # Edit: This is better as you get validated / parsed values, including defaults if applicable.
    parsed_body_by_alias = parsed_body.dict(by_alias=True)
    LOGGER.info(f"parsed_body_by_alias: {parsed_body_by_alias}")

    # If you just want "something" instead of "$something"
    LOGGER.info(f"parsed_body: {parsed_body}")
    LOGGER.info(f"parsed_body.something: {parsed_body.something}")

    return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

If you run the code then send a POST with body:

`{"$something": "bar"}`

you'll see something like:

```
INFO      xxx - __main__ - SomeModel.__fields__: {'something': ModelField(name='something', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None, alias='$something')}
INFO      xxx - __main__ - something_alias: $something
INFO      xxx - __main__ - raw_body: b'{"$something": "bar"}'
INFO      xxx - __main__ - parsed_body_by_alias: {'$something': 'bar'}
INFO      xxx - __main__ - parsed_body: something='bar'
INFO      xxx - __main__ - parsed_body.something: bar
INFO:     127.0.0.1:xxxxx - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned the new way :) But would there be a way without the use of Request? Preferably, I'd just like to use parsed_body with the set `alias` for `something`.

Comment: No worries and yes, I just edited my answer to show alternatives. Depending on how you're using it you might want to get the alias name of `something` by looking it up in the model's fields, or alternatively you might just want a dict of the parsed payload with the alias names. The edited answer illustrates these different methods now.